# Python on the AWS Beanstalk. How to snapshot custom logs?

Tags: python, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-logging

I'm developing python application which works on aws beanstalk environment. For error handling and debugging proposes I write logs to custom lof file on the directory /var/logs/.

What should I do in order to have ability snapshot logs from Elastic beanstalk management console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need have ability to snapshot log files from Beanstalk management console, you should just write you log files to "/opt/python/log/" folder. Elastic beanstalk scripts use this folder for log tailing.

Comment: I get Permission denied when I try that.

Comment: Chuck what exactly did you try?

Comment: logging.basicConfig(filename='/opt/python/log/my_log.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

Answer (score 24):

Expanding on Vadim911 (and my own comment), I solved the problem using a config file in [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html). Here is the python code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/opt/python/log/my.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Here is the .ebextensions config file code:

```
files:
  "/opt/python/log/my.log" :
   mode: "000666"
   owner: ec2-user
   group: ec2-user
   content: |
       # Askbot log file
```

The contents of this file (along with other log files) is available using the Logs snapshot function on the AWS elastic beanstalk console.

Comment: True, but there is no need to create the file in `.ebextensions`, as `logging` will do that for you when the file-handler is first initialized. If you run into a `PermissionError`, try removing the log file at the end of `container_commands` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549321).