# Python, Flask, Elasticbeanstalk Logging

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, logging, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use Elasticbeanstalk to deploy a Flask REST API. Logging and the application works with no issues on my test system. However, I am not getting the logs from the ebs instance using the request logs from AWS console.

Read stackoverflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038135/python-on-the-aws-beanstalk-how-to-snapshot-custom-logs) and AWS [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) but couldn't set it up correctly.

My application logging setup:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler('/opt/python/log/application.log', maxBytes=1024,backupCount=5)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
application = Flask(__name__)
application.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Usage:

```
logger.debug(email)
```

Config file in .ebextensions (tried with and without)

```
files:
  "/opt/python/log/application.log" :
   mode: "000666"
   owner: ec2-user
   group: ec2-user
   content: |
      # Python log file
```

When I request last 100 lines of logs there are no logs except what I put in the content section in ebextension config.

```
-------------------------------------
/opt/python/log/application.log
-------------------------------------
# Python log file
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I am having the same issue, can't see any errors in any other log and application seems to be running normally except for the logs.

Comment: How did you solve your issue?!

Comment: Writing to `/opt/python/log` should work, without explicitly creating the file in `.ebextensions`. If you do create the file in `.ebextensions`, make sure that owner and/or group are `wsgi` (with write permission), because your Python app will run as `wsgi:wsgi`. Also see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549321).